How do I make sure I am using fastdds intra for communication?
Within a process, I use a participant to create a reader and writer. They communicate with each other. How can I determine that they are using intra to communicate?
Two participants with identical 8 first bytes on the GuidPrefix_t are considered to be running in the same process, and therefore intra-process delivery is used.
but i only have one participant
and i had make the xml to this
<library_settings>
    <intraprocess_delivery>FULL</intraprocess_delivery> <!-- OFF | USER_DATA_ONLY | FULL -->
</library_settings>

<library_settings>
    <intraprocess_delivery>OFF</intraprocess_delivery> <!-- OFF | USER_DATA_ONLY | FULL -->
</library_settings>

Within a process, the reader and writer created by a participant, when intraprocess_delivery is OFF, the first eight digits of the guid are also the same.
